# PRML Book: Calculus of Variance

Tags: machine-learning, notation, calculus

I am reading through Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning (PRML) Appendix D (page 705).

Here is my question: what does the term $O(\epsilon ^ 2)$ in equation (D.1) and (D.2) stand for?

[image: screenshot for equation D1 and D2]

Comment: This is the "big O" notation. Posts on Cross Validated like this one may help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/279547/big-o-and-little-o-notation-explained.